# Display more data in an HTML/ASP page without refreshing the page

Tags: html, iframe, text, asp-classic, refresh

I've seen other sites do it, but I'm not sure what it's called or where to begin...

I want more content to be displayed on a page, but without having to actually refresh (via the browser refresh button or META refresh tag on that page).

Currently my page is HTML / Classic ASP and writes out data from a text file on the server.  That text file is being populated with data from a command-line tool running on the server (that's the only way, I can't touch/redesign/re-code this).  What I have now is a .asp page that when refreshed, uses the RealLine method to write what's in that text file, and I refresh that .asp page in an iframe every 3 seconds until the last line appears (which I know in advance) and when that string is found I take away the META refresh cause I'm "done" displaying any more info.

What I would like to do, hopefully avoiding Java (many won't have it installed) or JavaScript (I suspect some users will have that disabled), is load the page and have it fill in more information from the text file as it appears.  Possible?  How/what's that called?  Would greatly appreciate code samples if available.

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid using js in some capacity.  (I suppose you could use client side VBScript instead if your page only needed to work in Internet Explorer).  Anyway, take a look at this example.  It could just as easily call an asp page as a php one. http://codingx.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/update-content.html

Comment: 1st javascript and Java it's not the same thing. Supposing that you don't want to deal with applet/servlet (Java) or with Ajax (javascript). I think that your only way to do is implementing something in flash (that i consider nasty and obsolete). I will use Ajax if you ask.

Comment: Not many clients will have JavaScript disabled at all. Otherwise they will not be able to log into most of their regular haunts. Also, you refer to them as "clients" rather "visitors" so they must be logged in to read your page?

Comment: one the ASP page has been sent you're pretty much done. The best way to poll for, and update, a stream of data would be via Ajax, either rolling your own or (easier) using something like jQuery. Have you stats that show a significant number of users have javascript disabled?

Comment: I see, so Ajax and jQuery it is, I'm willing to try it and we'll see if anyone complains it's not working.  I would prefer not to be dependent on an external domain (or active Internet connection) like googleapis.com for this to work, so I could just serve the needed .js file from my own webserver, right?  Anyone have a code example?

Comment: If you know in advance which is the last line, why do you have to do it with a refresh? Why don't you just "stream" the entire contents in one shot?